# How do you add a computed column to a Table with correct column SQL

Tags: sql, select, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to add a computed column in the "DQ_MONITORING_RESULT" table. I want the status_1 to return "GREEN" if the values in COUNT_SOURCE_TABLE and "COUNT_RPT_TABLE MATCH.
(Edit: I am writhing the queries in Snowflake)

This is what I have tried.

```
ALTER TABLE "DQ_MONITORING_RESULT"
ADD (STATUS_1) AS (CASE WHEN COUNT_SOURCE_TABLE = COUNT_RPT_TABLE THEN 'GREEN' END)
```

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 0):

It's poorly documented by Snowflake (in my opinion) but you can do this by setting the column default to a simple SQL statement. Look at the DEFAULT optional parameter [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the documentation ([ALTER TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html)), you must use the keyword COLUMN and provide the TYPE of the resulting column:

> ADD COLUMN <col_name> <col_type> AS ( <expr> )

Example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE DQ_MONITORING_RESULT
ADD COLUMN STATUS_1 STRING AS (CASE WHEN COUNT_SOURCE_TABLE = COUNT_RPT_TABLE THEN 'GREEN' END);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not currently possible (have been looking for a way)

The table, unfortunately, needs to be reloaded with the column added on creation

According to their docs
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html
the only way a default value can be added is if it is a sequence.

It is supposedly done this way to prevent unexpected behavior where all instances before the column creation are null.